# OpenTok Android Lib How to Show publisher View (Camera Preview) in Round shape

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, opentok

I am Using OpenTok Android SDK 2.4+ 
(https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/)

Currently in SDK it's Showing the Publisher(Camera Preview) in Square Area but I wants it in Round Shape (Publisher Camera view in Round shape).

**Note**: PublisherView using OpenGL GLSurfaceView to show Camera Preview.

I am using attached "CustomVideoRenderer.java" Class by Extending class "BaseVideoRenderer".
I am not familiar with the OpenGL so not able to understand what I should change in Code.

So Please help me to Get Out of it..
TO Display Publisher View in Round Shape.

```
public class CustomVideoRenderer extends BaseVideoRenderer {

private Context mContext;

private GLSurfaceView mView;
private MyRenderer mRenderer;

static class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {


    int mTextureIds[] = new int[3];
    float[] mScaleMatrix = new float[16];

    private FloatBuffer mVertexBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer mTextureBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer mDrawListBuffer;

    boolean mVideoFitEnabled = true;
    boolean mVideoDisabled = false;

    // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
    static final int TEXTURECOORDS_PER_VERTEX = 2;

    static float mXYZCoords[] = {-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // top left
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
            1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f // top right
    };

    static float mUVCoords[] = {0, 0, // top left
            0, 1, // bottom left
            1, 1, // bottom right
            1, 0}; // top right

    private short mVertexIndex[] = {0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3}; // order to draw
    // vertices

    private final String vertexShaderCode = "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;"
            + "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n"
            + "attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;\n"
            + "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" + "void main() {\n"
            + "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n"
            + "  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;\n" + "}\n";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode = "precision mediump float;\n"
            + "uniform sampler2D Ytex;\n"
            + "uniform sampler2D Utex,Vtex;\n"
            + "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n"
            + "void main(void) {\n"
            + "  float nx,ny,r,g,b,y,u,v;\n"
            + "  mediump vec4 txl,ux,vx;"
            + "  nx=vTextureCoord[0];\n"
            + "  ny=vTextureCoord[1];\n"
            + "  y=texture2D(Ytex,vec2(nx,ny)).r;\n"
            + "  u=texture2D(Utex,vec2(nx,ny)).r;\n"
            + "  v=texture2D(Vtex,vec2(nx,ny)).r;\n"

            + "  y=1.0-1.1643*(y-0.0625);\n" // Invert effect
            // + "  y=1.1643*(y-0.0625);\n" // Normal renderer

            + "  u=u-0.5;\n" + "  v=v-0.5;\n" + "  r=y+1.5958*v;\n"
            + "  g=y-0.39173*u-0.81290*v;\n" + "  b=y+2.017*u;\n"
            + "  gl_FragColor=vec4(r,g,b,1.0);\n" + "}\n";

    ReentrantLock mFrameLock = new ReentrantLock();
    Frame mCurrentFrame;

    private int mProgram;
    private int mTextureWidth;
    private int mTextureHeight;
    private int mViewportWidth;
    private int mViewportHeight;

    public MyRenderer()
    {
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mXYZCoords.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mVertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        mVertexBuffer.put(mXYZCoords);
        mVertexBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer tb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mUVCoords.length * 4);
        tb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mTextureBuffer = tb.asFloatBuffer();
        mTextureBuffer.put(mUVCoords);
        mTextureBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mVertexIndex.length * 2);
        dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mDrawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
        mDrawListBuffer.put(mVertexIndex);
        mDrawListBuffer.position(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
    {
        gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,fragmentShaderCode);

        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram(); // create empty OpenGL ES
        // Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader); // add the vertex
        // shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment
        // shader to
        // program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);

        int positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram,
                "aPosition");
        int textureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram,
                "aTextureCoord");

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4,
                mVertexBuffer);

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureHandle,
                TEXTURECOORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                TEXTURECOORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4, mTextureBuffer);

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureHandle);

        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
        int i = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "Ytex");
        GLES20.glUniform1i(i, 0); /* Bind Ytex to texture unit 0 */

        i = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "Utex");
        GLES20.glUniform1i(i, 1); /* Bind Utex to texture unit 1 */

        i = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "Vtex");
        GLES20.glUniform1i(i, 2); /* Bind Vtex to texture unit 2 */

        mTextureWidth = 0;
        mTextureHeight = 0;
    }

    static void initializeTexture(int name, int id, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(name);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
                width, height, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
                GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    }

    void setupTextures(Frame frame) {
        if (mTextureIds[0] != 0) {
            GLES20.glDeleteTextures(3, mTextureIds, 0);
        }
        GLES20.glGenTextures(3, mTextureIds, 0);

        int w = frame.getWidth();
        int h = frame.getHeight();
        int hw = (w + 1) >> 1;
        int hh = (h + 1) >> 1;

        initializeTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0, mTextureIds[0], w, h);
        initializeTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1, mTextureIds[1], hw, hh);
        initializeTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE2, mTextureIds[2], hw, hh);

        mTextureWidth = frame.getWidth();
        mTextureHeight = frame.getHeight();
    }

    void updateTextures(Frame frame) {
        int width = frame.getWidth();
        int height = frame.getHeight();
        int half_width = (width + 1) >> 1;
        int half_height = (height + 1) >> 1;
        int y_size = width * height;
        int uv_size = half_width * half_height;

        ByteBuffer bb = frame.getBuffer();
        // If we are reusing this frame, make sure we reset position and
        // limit
        bb.clear();

        if (bb.remaining() == y_size + uv_size * 2) {
            bb.position(0);

            GLES20.glPixelStorei(GLES20.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
            GLES20.glPixelStorei(GLES20.GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureIds[0]);
            GLES20.glTexSubImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width,
                    height, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                    bb);

            bb.position(y_size);
            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureIds[1]);
            GLES20.glTexSubImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0,
                    half_width, half_height, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
                    GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);

            bb.position(y_size + uv_size);
            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE2);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureIds[2]);
            GLES20.glTexSubImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0,
                    half_width, half_height, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
                    GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);
        } else {
            mTextureWidth = 0;
            mTextureHeight = 0;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        mViewportWidth = width;
        mViewportHeight = height;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        mFrameLock.lock();
        if (mCurrentFrame != null && !mVideoDisabled) {
            GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

            if (mTextureWidth != mCurrentFrame.getWidth()
                    || mTextureHeight != mCurrentFrame.getHeight()) {
                setupTextures(mCurrentFrame);
            }
            updateTextures(mCurrentFrame);

            Matrix.setIdentityM(mScaleMatrix, 0);
            float scaleX = 1.0f, scaleY = 1.0f;
            float ratio = (float) mCurrentFrame.getWidth()
                    / mCurrentFrame.getHeight();
            float vratio = (float) mViewportWidth / mViewportHeight;

            if (mVideoFitEnabled) {
                if (ratio > vratio) {
                    scaleY = vratio / ratio;
                } else {
                    scaleX = ratio / vratio;
                }
            } else {
                if (ratio < vratio) {
                    scaleY = vratio / ratio;
                } else {
                    scaleX = ratio / vratio;
                }
            }

            Matrix.scaleM(mScaleMatrix, 0,
                    scaleX * (mCurrentFrame.isMirroredX() ? -1.0f : 1.0f),
                    scaleY, 1);

            int mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram,
                    "uMVPMatrix");
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false,
                    mScaleMatrix, 0);

            GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, mVertexIndex.length,
                    GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mDrawListBuffer);
        } else {
            //black frame when video is disabled
            gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
            GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        }
        mFrameLock.unlock();
    }

    public void displayFrame(Frame frame) {
        mFrameLock.lock();
        if (this.mCurrentFrame != null) {
            this.mCurrentFrame.recycle();
        }
        this.mCurrentFrame = frame;
        mFrameLock.unlock();
    }

    public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode) {
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        return shader;
    }

    public void disableVideo(boolean b) {
        mFrameLock.lock();

        mVideoDisabled = b;

        if (mVideoDisabled) {
            if (this.mCurrentFrame != null) {
                this.mCurrentFrame.recycle();
            }
            this.mCurrentFrame = null;
        }

        mFrameLock.unlock();
    }

    public void enableVideoFit(boolean enableVideoFit) {
        mVideoFitEnabled = enableVideoFit;
    }
}

public CustomVideoRenderer(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;

    mView = new GLSurfaceView(context);
    mView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

    mRenderer = new MyRenderer();
    mView.setRenderer(mRenderer);

    mView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
}

@Override
public void onFrame(Frame frame) {
    mRenderer.displayFrame(frame);
    mView.requestRender();
}

@Override
public void setStyle(String key, String value) {
    if (BaseVideoRenderer.STYLE_VIDEO_SCALE.equals(key)) {
        if (BaseVideoRenderer.STYLE_VIDEO_FIT.equals(value)) {
            mRenderer.enableVideoFit(true);
        } else if (BaseVideoRenderer.STYLE_VIDEO_FILL.equals(value)) {
            mRenderer.enableVideoFit(false);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onVideoPropertiesChanged(boolean videoEnabled) {
    mRenderer.disableVideo(!videoEnabled);
}

@Override
public View getView() {
    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mView.onResume();
}
```

}

Comment: You got any solution for this ? I'm also looking for same.

Comment: I finally figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/reference/com/opentok/android/Session.SessionOptions.html

You can have returned a TextureViews with TextureViews() and then the usual methods to have rounded corner seems to work.

Comment: The only problem is that the phone is getting heating up to a point it closes after around 30 minutes.